# How can I run jobs in parallel in Spark application?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am running spark. For my experiments, I'm aiming to run multi-jobs simultaneously (I mean a job is a spark action).

I've seen several methods on the internet, but I'm not sure how to apply them to the benchmarks I'm trying to use, HiBench* and TPC-H**, so I'm asking.

In other words, I want to use the Fair Scheduler on HiBench, or TPC-H.

*https://github.com/Intel-bigdata/HiBench
**https://github.com/ssavvides/tpch-spark

I tried 2 things

1. I put both query codes in a scala file.
2. and while running it, I put 'spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty' in the code, but Fair Scheduler doesn't use multiple pools.

[This is what i want!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSoId.png)
this picture is just a example of what i want!